How to change sda2 as a boot partition on running device

This image represent sda1(*) as a boot partition is there any possibility to change sda2 as a boot partition on a live running device. any any idea to extend size of sda1 of a running device with out data loss.

The /dev/sda disk seems to be essentially fully in use. You would need to extend it first. If this is a virtual machine (as suggested by the small size of the disk), the procedure for that depends on your virtualization solution (KVM? VirtualBox? Xen? Something else?). If sda2 is your root partition and there is no LVM, ZFS or BtrFS on it, then extending it is possible, but moving it (as would be required in order to extend sda1) is not possible while that partition is in use as the root filesystem. If sda2 is already set up with LVM, ZFS or BtrFS, then maybe - more info needed.

1.1G for boot and you don't have enuogh space? Maybe you need to tidy out some of the old kernels/initrds.

Note that whether the "active flag" (*) matters depends entirely on the bootloader in use. For example grub2 doesn't leverage it at all.

Answering directly to your question, you can mark another partition as bootable with fdisk and the option "a". Just run fdisk /dev/sda, use the option "a" and select the partition 2. This will just edit the MBR table and it won't be destructive (although your current boot partition will stop working).
But probably you want to merge both partitions because one of them is full, which is not an option without copying everything to another disk becore. You have tagged ubuntu, kali-linux and arch-linux, so I don't know which distro you are using. It seems like you should reinstall everything to a bigger disk or enlarge your current one.
Reference for the bootable flag: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-set-or-change-boot-partition-flag-on-linux
